# how to make code more compact in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encryption

i'm building a HTML website but i need very long code, and the web-hosting-service can't handle all the code, is there a way i can use the code without putting it in my HTML? I tried encrypting it using CryptoJS and use the encrypted version, but the code is too big  so when i decrypt it, it returns nothing, or the code i used did not work. This is the code i used for CryptoJS:

```
function encrypt(data, key) {
  var hexData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
  return hexData.substring(0, 10);
}

function decrypt(data, key) {
  var hexData = data.padEnd(20, '0');
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: 
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hexData.substring(0, 20))}, key, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, 
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

And i used this code in the devtools console to get the encrypted version:

```
console.log(encrypt("text", "123"));
```

Let's say it returns "Da342S342x",
I used this code to eval the code:

```
eval(decrypt("Da342S342x", "123"));
```

Is this code correct? If it is correct, does anyone have a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Try minification

Comment: You can also separate the HTML and JS code into two separate files and import the JS into your  HTML.

Comment: 1: I tried using minification, but all the minification sites i tried couldn't handle the code, 2: The JS code is too big for one seperate file too.

Comment: Try multiple JS files and import them in the correct order. Also, what's the file size?

Comment: File size is 17MB, way too big for my web hosting service and most of the minifiers.

Comment: What exactly is MultipleJS?

Comment: I meant to split your JS files into multiple JS files till the size of each of them comes under the allowed limit.

Comment: The code is very long. So i think splitting the code would take very long time...

Comment: 17MB JS!?!?!? Are you compiling 3D game engines to wasm or something? I worked on the wasm port of SNES9x and even it wasn't that big.

Comment: It is a 3D game :)

Comment: You may need to consider scaling your host to meet your programs needs, instead of scaling your program to meet your hosts capabilities. In other words, spend a few extra dollars for a better host.

Comment: I know that's a solution, but is there a way I can encrypt the code in a way that returns a code of say 20 characters, and run it with eval(decrypt("code", "123"));?

Comment: Encryption is the wrong way to make a code more compact. Moreover, the posted code does not work anyway: Neither may any part of the ciphertext be ignored, nor may the salt be ignored when using a key derivation function (as is the case with a string as key).

Comment: Why would it take a long time to split the file? Unless it's a total mess, all you need to do is move some of the functions/classes in different files...

Comment: It is a total mess...